# XPages - Can't instantiate class: 'Cannot find class <<classname>> in NSF'

Tags: xpages

I have an XPages application that has been running quite happily for the last couple of years.

The application uses some Java classes as converters that are used to convert data entry on certain fields to upper case, proper case, etc. This functionality has been present and working since the app was first deployed.

Today I was asked to make a change to one of the pages, adding a new field. The change was made in a test copy of the database, the app rebuilt and tested and all was fine.

The same change was then promoted into the live database, but after being rebuilt the error
    Can't instantiate class: 'Cannot find class uk.co.xxx.beans.UpperCase in NSF'. 
is being returned.

I have tried rebuilding the app and cleaning the project numerous times without success. I have also tried amending the code in the Java class and rebuilding.

If I remove all references to the UpperCase class it then complains about the ProperCase class. It appears as if the app has lost its reference to the Java classes and rebuilding isn't fixing the problem.

As an interim solution I have removed all uses of these classes so that users can at least display the page - but this is obviously not a long term solution. As soon as I reinstate one instance and rebuild, the error returns.

The only change in the app has been the addition of the new field. Removing it makes no difference.

Can you suggest anything else I can try and what may be causing the problem?

Comment: Where are the classes deployed in the db? 8.5.3 has some issues with the Code/Java element, so you might be better off moving them to a (custom) WEB-INF/src folder.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. The classes are already deployed in WEB-INF/src. In fact, the answer was much simpler than I was looking for. It seems that this src folder was no longer in the build path. I have no idea how that happened. Have you ever seen this (other than a developer physically removing it)?

Comment: Many times :-( When it happens the build path is reset to its default state: it removes all custom entries, including jars added from the `lib` folder. I'm currently on 9.0.1 (server & client) and am still seeing this occurring quite frequently. Although I'm not 100% sure it doesn't seem to be related to the build process, but rather to something else in Designer (like opening or replicating an app).

Comment: Ran into the similar issue: on one server app works fine, but after I copied app to the second server (different domain) and signed it by new Admin - I get only Error 500 in Web-browser, and "Can't instantiate class" error in console and logs... What can be issue for this?? Domino 9.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Open production db in designer and using Navigator view open WebContent/WEB-INF and delete classes folder. Then rebuild the app or refresh it from template again.

Sometimes classes are not updated correctly. I've seen it few times.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried this and, although it did not directly fix the problem, it did show me where to find the .class files. And I could see that there were no .class files present for these particular classes - which led me to checking the build path for the project (see my comment above). Ultimately a more obvious cause (and a simpler solution) than I was expecting and looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this too (domino 8.5.3).  I recompile until it eventually works. With a restart of the http task thrown in for good measure. How are you deploying the classes within the db or as jar files in lib/ext?

Comment: Thx for your reply, Jason. Classes are deployed within the db. This is an 8.5.3 server too. I have seen the same message before - but normally one more rebuild sorts it. The fact that the test db rebuilt fine 5 mins earlier is a bit weird. I'll keep trying on the rebuilds & get the admins to restart http - but that won't happen until Monday, now.

Comment: I think you'd be better off deploying them outside the nsf if you can. All my experiences of deploying (servlets primarily) within the DB have been bad. This week I had a headless xpage throw exceptions despite running perfectly for weeks without any code change. I replaced the replica and it ran fine again. Apologies for the lack of detail. Typing on iPhone :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with 8.53 FP2 with the same "can't instantiate errors" if accessed by a designer client.  I even put a PRD in at IBM for it.

In order to fix this problem we had to update to the server and clients to FP5. We had a work around before we could update the FP5.   We had to modify how the application was rolled out.  Once the database was updated from a template we had to do a clean then a build while use our Application ID used for signing applications.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639571

JDAE8ZV2CX
XPage With Java Design Element Breaks When Domino Designer opens after applying 8.5.3 Fix Pack 2 interim fix of any 853 Fix Pack 2/Fix Pack 3 hotfix